# iText formatting tables

Tags: java, itext

I'm generating a PDF document (for those who have seen his before, yes still) using the `iText5` library. Compliments to Bruno Lowagie; I've found it to be a really great API!

However, part of my task is to format some phrases. I used a nested `PdfPTable` to format the data, but I'm getting bizarre spacing issues. Here is an example of the problem I'm facing:

[image]

As you can see, rows with only a couple of phrases in them tend to have huge gaps in between them. I can understand **why** this is happening; the rows above are stretching the table. Is there a way to only make the table as big as it needs to be, and no larger?

**Code**

*Generating the prices collection*

I'm creating the prices with this snippet:

```
 Paragraph pricePara = new Paragraph();
 pricePara.add(price);
 pricePara.add(generateBreakLine());
 pricePara.add(time);
 pricePara.add(generateBreakLine());
 allPrices.add(pricePara);
```

where `generateBreakLine()` returns an empty `Paragraph` object.

*Adding them into the cell*

I add them into the cell with the following snippet:

```
 // 5 is just the amount of prices we can fit on one line.
 PdfPTable pricesCellValue = new PdfPTable(elements.size() > 5 ? 5 : elements.size());
    // Make it appear that the prices are just horizontal, as opposed to in a table.
    pricesCellValue.getDefaultCell().setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);

    // Cycle through each price. Add to cell. Add cell to the table.
    for (com.lowagie.text.Element elem : elements) {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell((Paragraph) elem);
        cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        cell.setPadding(2);
        pricesCellValue.addCell(cell);
    }
    return pricesCellValue;
```

The above snippet, I believe, is where I can make sure the table is only as wide as it needs to be, as opposed to filling up all the space around it. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Solved it by padding in empty cells!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved

Found a simple way of fixing it. In stead of changing the amount of columns based on the number of prices, I make sure the column number is always 5, and then append empty cells on:

```
  if(elements.size() < 5)
    {
        int diff = 5 - elements.size();

        for(int x = 0; x < diff; x++)
        {
            pricesCellValue.addCell(new Paragraph(" "));
        }
    }
```